# Bosch Fridge is making a high-pitched whining sound, generally when the compressor is on

Tags: refrigerator, appliances

Here is a video of the sound:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o9Vkfu2lYcc8RDnxAjh2p4LYazjSTRDn/view?usp=sharing

800 Series French Door Bottom Mount Refrigerator 36'' Easy clean stainless steel
Model Number (E-Nr):  B21CT80SNS/02

A Bosch technician came, couldn't reproduce the sound, and assumed it was the fan and said he'd come back to replace it

But I think the sound is too constant to be coming from a fan? Not sure.  It's a new fridge

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about appliances, not home improvement.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson "Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances" is explicitly on-topic.

Comment: What makes the sound start and stop? Is it exactly when the compressor is on? If not, when? If you turn the fridge thermostat up (warmer) and the freezer down, does it happen? How about the reverse?

Comment: It's exactly when the compressor is on, the maintenance man came and opened the fridge to warm it up and it didn't reproduce.  It doesn't reproduce 100% of the time.  Just not sure what the possible sources could be

Comment: I could only hear rumbling, but a possible issue is an over charged system tripping a high pressure safety. This is a mechanical safety and normally in much larger units but I have seen 1 in a large refrigerator) sorry I don’t remember the brand. If it happens at start up and continues until shut down but on the next start it doesn't or is inconsistent. I have seen this several times when a system is charged in cool locations then used in a much warmer time causing the system pressure to be higher because of the ambient heat but that’s my only guess from the text as I can’t hear it.